# How can I find out which rows (if any) have a non-unique value in a column?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have the following table in my SQL Server 2012 database:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Problem](
    [ProblemId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SubTopicId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ReferenceId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProblemStatusId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Locator] [nvarchar](50) NULL
)
```

The Locator is supposed to be unique but I think there are some cases where more than one row has the same value for locator.  How can I find out if this is the case and also if so then how can I identify the rows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to perform a fast and dirty check, you can try adding a `UNIQUE` constraint (or index) on `Locator`. If it succeeds, you have no duplicates. If it fails, you have.

Problem with the above is that SQL-Server treats `NULL` values in a rather non-standard way and the constraint/index creation will fail even if you have 2 rows with `NULL` and no other real duplicate values. To avoid that (and if you want to allow more than one Nulls but no duplicate non-null values), you can check with a filtered unique index:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Locator_UQ           -- choose a name for the index
ON Problem (Locator)
WHERE Locator IS NOT NULL ;
```

---

To find the duplicates (and check at the same time), one way is:

```
SELECT *
FROM
  ( SELECT *,
           Cnt = COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Locator)
    FROM Problem
  ) AS p
WHERE Cnt > 1 
ORDER BY Locator, ProblemId ;
```

If the above returns 0 rows, there are no duplicates in `Locator`.

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from table where Locator in 
   (
    select Locator from table group by Locator having count(*) > 1
   )
```

Answer (score 0):

Select Locator,count(*) as occurence from dbo.Problem group by Locator

--using where clause you can filter for duplicated locator like

where occurence>1

Answer (score 0):

If you have a large set of data then you could try this solution:

```
DECLARE @MyTable TABLE
(
    [ProblemId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [SubTopicId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Locator] [nvarchar](50) NULL
);

INSERT  @MyTable (SubTopicId, Locator)
SELECT  11, 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT  11, 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT  22, 'C' UNION ALL
SELECT  44, 'C' UNION ALL
SELECT  33, 'D' UNION ALL
SELECT  55, 'D'  UNION ALL
SELECT  22, 'D'  UNION ALL
SELECT  22, NULL;

SET STATISTICS IO ON;

SELECT  *
FROM
(
    SELECT  x.*,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.Locator ORDER BY x.ProblemId ASC) AS RowNumAsc,
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY x.Locator ORDER BY x.ProblemId DESC) AS RowNumDesc
    FROM    @MyTable x
) src
WHERE   NOT(src.RowNumAsc = 1 AND src.RowNumDesc = 1);
```